# How to do Device Authorisation Flow in supabase for kiosk device - custom jet

Tags: jwt, authorization, supabase

I'm new to supabase and trying to get it working with a flutter app.

An admin user wants to add a kiosk device to their account. The kiosk interacts with the public with a flutter app and collects survey info etc. The kiosk can insert or read from very specific tables. The admin user can use mobile flutter app to read the data from kiosk.

How do you authorise the kiosk - would you manually log it in with its own credentials? I saw https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/device-authorization-flow and now I think somehow the admin needs to signup the kiosk with a specified role and pass the token to the kiosk, then the kiosk uses that long lived token to make requests/insertions.

Is this the best way?

Maybe the easiest way is to create a kiosk user table and create my own kiosk login which passes in a password and the deviceId and that is passed on every insert?

Comment: Having each Kiosk device sign in is the way to go if you want to keep things secure. If you create your own "login", you won't be able to make it secure using RLS of Supabase.

Comment: That means each kiosk needs a dedicated email address to send the confirmation email that needs to be clicked or dedicated mobile for OTP. How can each end user admin user have their own collection of kiosks from a single account without admins logging in with their accounts?

Comment: They need unique something, email, phone number, Google or other social account. They need to be signed in somehow, or otherwise, the system would be hackable. One thing you could do is wait for the anonymous sign-in. Once anonymous sign-in lands, your kiosks will be able to sign in without any credentials, and then you could have some table to associate each kiosk with the parent account. Until then, it's not possible to securely associate the kiosks without them being signed in. https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/683